# Add Background Color into a Input Text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got some help to create the code below and I wonder who I should make the disable input text to have a yellow color. If I change into another input text, the disable one should should have a default background and the new disable input text should have a yellow background color.

I tried to add a code with this code

code `"$('.'+other_class).prop('style', 'background-color : yellow;' );"` but It didn't go so well.

Do you know how to solve this case?

A complementory. I need to have style and disabled at the same time. It is important that you use background with style because I'm using bootstrap.

Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/8NynQ/118/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=radio][name=test]').click(function(){
        var related_class=$(this).val();
        $('.'+related_class).prop('disabled',false);

        $('input[type=radio][name=test]').not(':checked').each(function(){
            var other_class=$(this).val();
            $('.'+other_class).prop('disabled',true);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can disabled fields to be yellow? `:disabled { background: #FF0 }`.

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/8NynQ/122/) what you want?

Comment: Almost. The one that is disabled should have a yellow background but not the one that is active. The active one shall have a default background. If you change the radio button, the new input text should be disabled and have a yellow background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use CSS styling in jQuery (javascript). It is better to keep your styles in separated files.

I added `:disabled` CSS selector to input in your styles

```
input[type="text"]:disabled{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I updated your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8NynQ/127/)

Comment: Please take a look above for more info.

Comment: It is almost correct. When you start the  https://jsfiddle.net/8NynQ/121/   I don't see the disabled input text to have a yellow background color.

Comment: Look at this, I removed css styling from jQuery and updated css https://jsfiddle.net/8NynQ/127/. Is it expected behaviour?

Comment: The answer is    jsfiddle.net/8NynQ/127

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

instead of:

```
$('.'+other_class).prop('style', 'background-color : yellow;' );
```

Do:

```
$('.' + other_class).css({'background-color': 'yellow'});
```

Comment: Please take a look above for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you're adding styling use the `.addClass()` function first I would much prefer using their `$('.'+other_class).addClass('yourClass')` functionality vs inline CSS

Keep your styles in the CSS file.

***BUT... No javascript needed. This can be done via CSS***

```
input[type="text"]:disabled {
    background:yellow;
}
```

Here is a link the the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8NynQ/118/)

Comment: Please take a look above for more info.